# Как мне поменять цвет границы fieldset при фокусе input'а?

Tags: html, css

```html
<fieldset>
                    <input type="number" name="first-number" class="number first-number" placeholder="Min" oninput="onInputChange()">
                    <legend style="font-size: 13px;">First number</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Коротко: никак.
Не коротко: CSS не умеет изменять стили родительских классов при изменении дочерних. Вариант изменять так, как вы хотите, есть только с использованием JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В рамках текущей разметки поменять цвет не получится, потому что (как верно отметил в комментарии @VladimirGonchar) CSS не умеет изменять стили родительских классов при изменении дочерних - это каскад, который идёт только сверху вниз.

Но можно ведь поменять разметку - обернуть всё родительским дивом, инпут поставить перед филдсетом, а с помощью позиционирования визуально переместить его внутрь. Тогда всё будет работать:

```css
fieldset {
  height: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.first-number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
.first-number:focus ~ fieldset {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" name="first-number" class="number first-number" placeholder="Min" oninput="onInputChange()">
  <fieldset>
       <legend style="font-size: 13px;">First number</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Очень хочется докопаться до вашей разметки. Одному полю не нужна обертка из `<fieldset>` и `<legend>` - эти теги существуют для разметки групп полей, так говорится в [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

И хоть CSS не позволяет обратиться к родителю, есть одно исключение и оно как раз вам подходит - это связка `<label>` + `<input>` + селектор `:focus-within`.

Не обращайте внимания, что итоговый вид в приведенном мной коде не полностью соответствует тому, что у вас, а именно нет надписи поверх рамки. Это можно решить небольшим количеством дополнительных стилей, а вот семантика и удобство пользования формой будут точно лучше при предложенном мной подходе.

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

label:focus-within {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for=x>
  Some label
  <br>
  <input id=x type=text>
</label>
```